# Telugu Characters in Android

Tags: android, utf-8

I have a table stored in SQL with English and Telugu Characters as shown. The SQL table shows the characters properly when I do a local query in the phpMyadmin SQL query.

When I do the query through PHP through POSTMAN or ANDROID STUDIO, the characters of Telugu are shown as ???

DETAILS:
Stored values in SQL

```
holDate         holDay       holDetails  
2021-01-13 Wednesday బుధ  Sankranthi భోగి
```

SQL Character set: utf8_general_ci

Android-side

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
jsonstring = object.toString();
```

Query

```
through PHP (Api.php?apicall=getHolData)
"SELECT `holDate`,`holDay`,`holDetails` FROM `holdata`"
```

Query Result

```
{"hols":[{"holDate":"2021-01-13","holDay":"Wednesday ???","holDetails":"Sankranthi ????"}}
```

Any suggestions please?

Adding PHP code

```
function getHolData(){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT `holDate`,`holDay`,`holDetails` FROM `holdata`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($holDate, $holDay, $holDetails);
    $hols = array(); 
    
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $hol  = array();
        $hol['holDate'] = $holDate; 
        $hol['holDay'] = $holDay; 
        $hol['holDetails'] = $holDetails; 
        array_push($hols, $hol); 
    }
    return $hols;  
}
```

Calling PHP

```
case 'getHolData':
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $response['hols'] = $db->getHolData();
    break;
```

Comment: If the issue also happens with postman, then the problem is probably not on the Android side, but on the server side. You probably need to ensure that you're using UTF-8 everywhere on your server.

Comment: The database and all tables are set to: SQL Character set/collations: utf8_general_ci.  Problem still persists

Comment: But the data isn't directly returned by MySQL, is it? There's also PHP in the mix.

Comment: Added the PHP code. Have tried to add the UTF-8 statement: mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8'); but do not know where to place it.

Comment: Added this line after connect "$this->con -> set_charset("utf8");" and now the result is coming like this --> {"hols":[{"holDate":"2021-01-13","holDay":"Wednesday \u0c2c\u0c41\u0c27","holDetails":"Sankranthi}

Comment: congrats, that looks correct.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. It worked in Android. Please put an answer with the same comments and shall select it.